# Unable to find matching line from backtrace in ruby 2.0, rspec 3.0

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec3

I got this error when running a feature spec using rspec 3.0, ruby 2.0.0p195 on Windows in Rails 4.0. Reading on Googles, I find that a fix was to use a specific version in rpsec 2.0 but nothing past that version. I thought I would have been long past that issue. Like others, I find that when I manually act out the steps of the feature, everything works as expected. There is no indicator of what line of the spec fails. Where should I look in Google to get past this issue? Or have I made a goof somewhere?

gemfile.lock

```
     rspec-core (3.0.2)
  rspec-support (~> 3.0.0)
rspec-expectations (3.0.2)
  diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
  rspec-support (~> 3.0.0)
rspec-mocks (3.0.2)
  rspec-support (~> 3.0.0)
rspec-rails (3.0.1)
  actionpack (>= 3.0)
  activesupport (>= 3.0)
  railties (>= 3.0)
  rspec-core (~> 3.0.0)
  rspec-expectations (~> 3.0.0)
  rspec-mocks (~> 3.0.0)
  rspec-support (~> 3.0.0)
rspec-support (3.0.2)
```

Fails here: _score_form.html.erb

```
 <%= simple_form_for [@site, @inspection, score] do |f| %>
   <%= f.input :note %>
   <%= f.button :submit, submit_text %>
 <% end %>
 <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
```

note_feature_spec.rb

```
 require 'spec_helper'

 feature "notes", js: true do
   background do
   @surveys = ["Loss", "Solutions"]
    @manager = FactoryGirl.create(:manager)
    @site = FactoryGirl.create(:site)
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, site_id: @site.id)
    @survey = FactoryGirl.create(:survey, name: "#{@surveys[1]}", user_id: @manager.id)
    @item_1 = FactoryGirl.create(:item, name: "item 1", survey_id: @survey.id, category: "Regular", sub_category: 
        'DEC')
@variance = FactoryGirl.create(:cash_variance)
end

scenario "appear when saved with a score" do
visit root_path
    click_link 'Login'
    fill_in 'Email', with: @manager.email
    fill_in 'Password', with: @manager.password
click_button 'Log in'
click_link ("#{@site.name}" + " #{@site.site_type}")
click_link 'New Inspection'
select("#{@survey.name}")
  click_button 'Start inspection'
  score = Score.where(inspection_id: Inspection.last.id, item_id: @item_1.id).first
expect(page).to have_content("@item.name")
expect(page).to have_css("note-act#{@score.id}")
end
end
```

relevant portion of scores_controller.rb

```
class ScoresController < ApplicationController
  def update
  @site = Site.find(params[:site_id])
  @inspection = @site.inspections.find(params[:inspection_id])
  @score = @inspection.scores.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @score.update_attributes(score_params)

      format.html {redirect_to edit_site_inspection_path(@site,@inspection), notice: 'Score was updated'}
      format.json {head :no_content}
      format.js
    else
      format.html { render action: 'edit'}
      format.json { render json: @score.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end

end

end
```

Top of error message:

```
   1) notes it appears when saved with a score
 Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `note' for #<Score:0x8acdb60>
 # ./app/views/inspections/_score_form.html.erb:2:in `block in _app_views_inspections__score_form_html_erb__524083191_68481552'
 # ./app/views/inspections/_score_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_inspections __score_form_html_erb__524083191_68481552'
 # ./app/views/inspections/_regular.html.erb:13:in `_app_views_inspections__regular_html_erb__743764807_72723960'
 # ./app/views/inspections/_clean_scores.html.erb:17:in `block (3 levels) in _app_views_inspections__clean_scores_html_erb___604997166_72361188'
 # ./app/views/inspections/_clean_scores.html.erb:15:in `each'
 # ./app/views/inspections/_clean_scores.html.erb:15:in `block (2 levels) in
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there is a migration missing, so it is as I suspected: a goof.